# Can I request companies to give me all the data they have on me when I'm visiting a country in the EU?

Tags: privacy, gdpr

I'm not a citizen of the EU, nor do I reside in the EU. But as a consumer, I welcome GDPR. It gives me some limited rights even though I'm not in the direct interests of the regulation.

Anyway, if I understand the regulation correctly, I'm covered by it if I visit / reside in a country in the EU (even if I'm not a citizen). Does this mean I can request companies to give me a copy of *all* the data they have on me when I visit, for example, France on vacation?

Answer (score 2):

It would seem that only the actions which are taken while present in the EU would be covered under the GDPR for entities based outside of the EU.

> This Regulation applies to the processing of personal data of data subjects **who are in the Union** by a controller or processor not established in the Union, where the processing activities are related to:
>
> - the offering of goods or services, irrespective of whether a payment of the data subject is required, to such data subjects in the Union;
> - or
>   the monitoring of their behaviour **as far as their behaviour takes place within the Union.**

[Source](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-3-gdpr/)

There may be cases centring on what the definition of *as far as their behaviour takes place within the Union* is, as this would allow companies to limit how much of their activities fall under GDPR.