# Facebook blocked my account until I consent to their new privacy policy under GDPR. If I consent now, will I be able to withdraw my consent later?

Tags: privacy, european-union, gdpr, data-ownership, data-protection

I am going to delete my Facebook account in a month, I can't do it now because I still use it for work. I live in the EU and Facebook has blocked access to my account unless I accept their privacy rules, which means giving up GDPR protections. I worry that if I accept their rules now, I won't be protected anymore by GDPR, and that even if I delete my Facebook account in the future, that I won't be able to request my data to be fully deleted with full protections of GDPR. In other words, I worry that agreeing to their privacy policy will override GDPR and that I won't be able request to delete the data they have about me anymore. Is my worry justified?

Comment: Where do Facebook say that you won't be protected by the GDPR? I find nothing suggesting that in:  https://www.facebook.com/about/privacy/

Comment: Since Facebook can't require you to give up GDPR protection, and because that's not even what they're doing, I can't see what question is here to be answered.

Comment: This question may be of interest: [link](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/28876/can-i-request-companies-to-give-me-all-the-data-they-have-on-me-when-im-visitin/29166#29166), it covers cases when the company is not EU based

Answer (score 3):

> I live in the EU and Facebook has blocked access to my account unless I accept their privacy rules, which means giving up GDPR protections.

Facebook operates in the EU and has EU data subjects, therefore Facebook is subject to GDPR.

You should be able to withdraw your consent. Article 7(3) says:

> The data subject shall have the right to withdraw his or her consent at any time. The withdrawal of consent shall not affect the lawfulness of processing based on consent before its withdrawal. Prior to giving consent, the data subject shall be informed thereof. It shall be as easy to withdraw as to give consent.